# toString method for inherited case class in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, tostring, case-class

I am facing some inconsistency in calling `toString` method for case-classes in Scala. The first code sample:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val jim = Person("jim", 42)
println(jim)
```

output: `Person(jim,42)`

For the next code sample I used a case class that extends `Exception`:

```
case class JimOverslept(msg: String) extends Exception
try {
  throw JimOverslept(msg = "went to bed late")
} catch {
  case e: JimOverslept => println(e)
}
```

output: `playground.CaseClassOutput$JimOverslept`

Actually, I would prefer the output like `JimOverslept(went to bed late)`

What is the reason the both outputs are so different? And what is the best way to obtain the output looks like desired one (`JimOverslept(went to bed late)`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [SLS 5.3.2 Case Classes](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes)

> Every case class implicitly overrides some method definitions of class
>   `scala.AnyRef` **unless a definition of the same method is already given
>   in the case class itself or a concrete definition of the same method
>   is given in some base class** of the case class different from AnyRef.

Now `toString` is already provided by base class in

```
case class JimOverslept(msg: String) extends Exception
```

where `Exception` extends base `Throwable` which provides `toString` definition. Hence try providing an override within the case class itself like so

```
case class JimOverslept(msg: String) extends Exception {
  override def toString: String = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(this)
}
```