# Several case classes with the same behavior in Scala

Tags: scala, exception, case-class, code-duplication

I define some case classes based on `Exception` with identical behavior ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61446999/tostring-method-for-inherited-case-class-in-scala/61447236#61447236))

```
case class Foo(msg: String) extends Exception {
    override def toString: String = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(this)
}
case class Bar(msg: String) extends Exception {
    override def toString: String = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(this)
}
case class Boo(msg: String) extends Exception {
    override def toString: String = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(this)
}
```

All these new exceptions repeat same code. I want to rid of redundant code duplication. I unsuccessfully tried to use interim common base class and traits. Please, help me remove excess code duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScalaRunTime._toString` takes a `Product` argument

```
def _toString(x: Product): String =
  x.productIterator.mkString(x.productPrefix + "(", ",", ")")
```

hence try defining

```
trait ProductException extends Exception with Product {
  override def toString: String = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(this)
}
```

and then

```
case class Foo(msg: String) extends ProductException
Foo("Live long and prosper")
// res1: Foo = Foo(Live long and prosper)
```

This works because case classes are implicitly `Product`s, for example, defnining

```
case class Foo(msg: String)
```

is expanded by compiler to something like

```
case class Foo(msg: String) extends Object with Product with Serializable
```